# Comparing two csv files and get the output as matching or not in new csv file

Tags: python, csv, data-mining, text-mining

I have two csv files. one is profile.csv another one is data.csv file.
The profile.csv has data under two columns such as company_name and job_description like this [profile.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEgsr.png).
The data.csv file has data under two columns such as company_name and job_description like this [data.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F3O9.png).

What i want is the description(qualification) of profile.csv has to be compare with description of data.csv. and get the output whether each description(Qualification) is matching or not...

**In my point of view the output has to come like this**

company         ----------------------

PPD GLOBAL LTD

job_description  ---------

Education to Bachelorâ€™s/advanced degree level in a scientific discipline  --Matching

Prior experience within regulatory medical writing --Matching

Excellent grammatical, editorial and proofreading skills --Matching

Effective organisational and planning skills  --Matching

Motivation, initiative and adaptability
Ability to work effectively in a team  --Matching

**So far I have tried this**

It is matching whole job_description only not each sentences...

```
import csv

with open('C:\\Users\\Izzath  Ali\\Desktop\\Data Mining\\profile.csv', 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile1:
    csvfile1_indices = dict((r[1], i) for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(csvfile1)))

with open('C:\\Users\\Izzath  Ali\\Desktop\\Data Mining\\data.csv', 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile2:
    with open('outputText-mining.csv', 'w') as results:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile2)
        writer = csv.writer(results)

        writer.writerow(next(reader, []) + ['status'])

        for row in reader:
            index = csvfile1_indices.get(row[1])
            if index is not None:
               message = '-- matching'
               writer.writerow(row + [message])

            else:
               message = '-- not matching'
               writer.writerow(row + [message])

 results.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to simplify your data structure to enable a demo:

```
file1 = """company1, "sent1. sent2. sent3"
company2, "sent4. sent5. sent6"
company3, "sent7. sent8. sent9"
"""

file2 = """companyA, "sent1. sent20. sent3"
companyB, "sent40. sent5."
companyC, "sent5. sent1. sent60"
"""
```

First I'll load the data into a data structure -- a list of dictionaries, one dictionary per company.

```
list_of_file1_company_dicts = []
for line in file1.split('\n'):
    company_dict = {}
    col = line.split(',')
    print('company:', col[0])
    list_of_sent = col[1].split('.')
    company_dict[col[0]] = list_of_sent
list_of_file1_company_dicts.append(company_dict)

list_of_file2_company_dicts = []
for line in file2.split('\n'):
    company_dict = {}
    col = line.split(',')
    print('company:', col[0])
    list_of_sent = col[1].split('.')
    company_dict[col[0]] = list_of_sent
list_of_file2_company_dicts.append(company_dict)
```

Then loop through the two data structures to look for intersections of the dictionary values

```
for file1_company_dict in list_of_file1_company_dicts:
    for company1_name, list_of_sent1 in file1_company_dict.items():
        for sent1 in list_of_sent1:
            for file2_company_dict in list_of_file2_company_dicts:
                for company2_name, list_of_sent2 in file2_company_dict.items():
                    for sent2 in list_of_sent2:
                        if sent1==sent2:
                            print(company1_name, company2_name)
```